# Tracepoints not available from network namespace

Tags: linux, ebpf, linux-namespaces

I want to use the linux tracepoints for a bpf application. However when I enter a network namespace no tracepoints/tracing events are available, e.g. `ls /sys/kernel/tracing` is empty.

Why is that and how can I access them from a network namespace?

**Steps to reproduce (as root):**

```bash
ip netns add x
ip netns exec x bash
ls /sys/kernel/tracing
```